# Android Firestore offline persistence and caching

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently working on an app in which a user answers a list of questions, and the answers are stored in Firestore. But I need to be able to write data to Firestore offline and while writing to the database once is fine, I Cant write multiple requests to the database without it overwriting the current cache.

With how the code was written, when I enable offline persistence, the data in the cache is overwritten every time a new write request is made. So how would I cache multiple writes without overwriting what is currently cached ?

Comment: Please share what you've done so far

Answer (score 0):

If the local cache of the database isn't what you need, then you should consider creating your own mechanism for caching using the [Room persistence library](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room). You can do as many operations as you want, and later when you consider, you can add it to Firestore.

Comment: Ideally I would like to cache the data locally and then push it onto the database when connection is restored. But how the code is currently written , every time a write request is done the cache data is overwritten

Comment: To achieve that, you should write code for that. If you already have some code that doesn't work the way you expect, please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: Hey Suhail. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?